# Why does the conditional operator care about types when used in string interpolation?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, conditional-operator, string-interpolation

A lot of us are all too familiar with accidental episodes of the `CS0173` compiler error, which is a type conversion error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'class1' and 'class2'

Today, I made an assumption was that I could use the conditional operator `?:` within string interpolation, and it wouldn't care about the type used for the consequent or alternative. In my case, I wanted to check a `long` to determine if it's value was less than zero, and if it was, display a `string` saying `Not Available`, and if it was not, then simply display the value of the long:

```
long x = 5;
string example = $"{(x < 0 ? "Not Available" : x)}";
```

This resulted in compiler error `CS0173` due to the consequent being of type `string` and the alternative being of type `long`. It's a simple fix by using `.ToString()`:

```
long x = 5;
string example = $"{(x < 0 ? "Not Available" : x.ToString())}";
```

But now I'm curious...

---

Why would the conditional operator `?:` even care about the type when utilized inside of string interpolation since the whole point is to display the string representation anyways?

Comment: Because it will be assigned to a type before it being interpolated (remember, C# is strong typed). In this case `string`.

Comment: @Magnetron makes sense lol maybe not enough coffee this morning ‍♀️

Comment: FYI this works with the latest c# version see here - [Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOwD4AEBMAjALABQBADGQQMwAEA3mXS3Qfo869wDYD2mAOZ0AHnQC8dAKwBuLtxa5CFOnBEQwABx5wJdACQAiBgAoxAHjoqA/HUMA5PjDoBBAG4QAljwjAdhuhBRAEoAX0M5UgVWJQBOEzUNbThgyO5QslCgA=) - here the documentation: [C# 9 Doku](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression.md)

Comment: @Magnetron Arguments to string interpolation are of type `object`, because it implicitly calls `ToString()` on them. With C# 9's improved target typing, the type of expression `x < 0 ? "Not Available" : x` can be resolved to `object` in this context and thus compiles, as per @RandRandom's example

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay yes, arguments to string interpolation are of type object, but the returning type of the ternary is not, which was what I was talking about (as my answer bellow). And yes, with the new C# 9 they changed the implementation, but the question is about why it's not allowed, which implies they're asking about prior versions of C#.

Comment: @Magnetron In C# 8 and below, the ternary expression in the question does not evaluate to any type at all; it results in a compilation error.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I think you misunderstood me. My comment and my answer are explaining why it gives a compilation error, I never said that OP example would be assigned to a type, because it is already stabilished it will give an error. OP already knows that outside the string interpolation it will give an error, their question was "Why does it give compilation error in the string interpolation" and I explained that was because the ternary operator evaluates to a type before being passed to the string interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operators don't know the context they're being used. Either cases `x+1` or `y=x+1` the `+` operator only knows that it is taking two arguments and returning the result. To illustrate, it's like

```
T Sum<T>(T numA, T numB){
//Do stuff
}
```

The same happens to `?:`, it's a method that takes three arguments and return the result. The result is strong typed, inferred from the inputs. Only then the result will be passed to the interpolation, which never happens in your case, since the ternary operator will give the compile time error, since it cannot implicit convert `long` to `string`.

Edit:
Now that is possible with C# 9, as @RandRandom pointed out in the comments, as they [changed the implementation of the ternary operator](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression.md).

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that the ternary conditional operator, `?:`, care about type when utilized inside string interpolation is faulty. Because it does not even need to be inside a string interpolation. c# is a strongly typed language (type of each variable is known, there is the `dynamic` keyword but that is a different story).

For example you cant even do the following because the type is not known (Is it long or string?)

```
long x = 5;
var example = x < 0 ? "Not Available" : x;
```